# I think "How can I defend Islam as being a peaceful religion?" is not opinion based

Tags: discussion

I think "[How can I defend Islam as being a peaceful religion?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37126/how-can-i-defend-islam-as-being-a-peaceful-religion)" is not opinion based. It is just ordinary question as other questions on this site. But there are many answers started to come which are not very full and solid.

Answer (score 2):

**Close reasons**:

The close reason *primarily opinion-based* was probably chosen as the closest available approximation to the actual close reason.  The StackExchange software only provides a small, limited number of close reasons.  I suspect the underlying close reason is closer to *argumentative*.

**Weighing users' opinions**:

> i think {How can I defend Islam as being a peaceful religion?} is not opinion based

That's fine, but your opinion is one person's opinion, and other people can reasonably disagree (and, given the two votes to close, it seems others do disagree).

StackExchange has a voting system in place, where users can vote to reopen questions.  During beta, 500 reputation enables a user to [cast reopen votes](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

One can present reasons for disagreeing with a close vote here at meta.Islam.SE, and users can decide if they want to vote to reopen.  But you haven't given any reason other than "I think..."  (Consider expanding on your reasons by editing your post.)

**Offensive content**:

We should also be cautions that the responses this question might be offensive to readers, may be prejudiced, and may even be regarded as [hate speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hate_speech):

> Hate speech is speech that attacks a person or group on the basis of attributes such as gender, ethnic origin, religion, race, disability, or sexual orientation.

Indeed, "rude or abusive" is a reason to flag here:

[image: Rude or abusive flag]

From the [Help Center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice):

> Don't be a jerk. These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them:
>
> - Bigotry of any kind. **Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on** race, gender, sexual orientation, **religion,** etc. **will not be tolerated. At all.**

And as pointed out at [meta.StackExchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109390/what-is-considered-hate-speech), the StackExchange [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal) says:

> Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that [...] (d) is libelous, defamatory, abusive, threatening, harassing, hateful, offensive or otherwise violates any law or right of any third party [...]

This is available by clicking at the bottom of the Islam.SE page:

[image: Link to Terms of Service]

Moreover, an answer asserting that Islam is inherently violent could encourage violence.  (What if an otherwise peaceful Muslim actually believed such an answer?)

I'd say there's good reasons to err on the side of caution with this one.

Comment: Apart from being false in its suggestions about legality, this answer misunderstand the purpose of the stackexchange network. Answers stating facts about Islam as a set of ideas and statistical knowledge about the opinions of Muslims are not hate speech as those things are not attacks on people, they are descriptions of the world; just as an answer that says that kuffar will be tortured in hell forever is not hate speech, it is an accurate description of Islamic doctrine, however hateful it may be.

Comment: If we cannot describe aspects of Islam that someone - Muslims or Non-Muslims - may take offense to, then islam.se has to be closed down; islam.se is decidedly not a Muslim site, it is a site about Islam. Many users will be deeply offended by the suggestion that dissenters or gays or "witches" or adulterers should be killed, but this is without the shadow of a doubt the status of sexually active gays, apostates who don't hide in the closet, people who practice magic, and people who swap spouses, as we find in fiqh discourse. It has to be possible to say these things on islam.se.

Comment: Just as Non-Muslims may take offense to see those aspects of Islam, Muslims may also take offense to see aspects of Islam accurately portrayed - that doesn't make the portrayal inaccurate, or bigotry, or hate speech.